# How to completely uninstall MySQL on Windows?

Tags: windows, mysql, uninstall

How can I completely remove MySQL on Windows 7?

When I reinstall it, it is asking for the old password, so the uninstall is not complete, there is some remaining data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [RevoUninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/start_freeware_download.html) and begin the MySQL uninstall. It'll run the packaged uninstaller for the Windows version of MySQL and also search for leftover registry entries and files/folders. The link above should automatically start the free-version (which we use here at work and found it to be very helpful). Their main site is: [RevoUninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)